# how can i improve the search using date in sql database in java

Tags: java, sql-server

I made a software using the java language and MS SQL Server as the database.  The problem am facing is that when I search for a date range using two dates, it's giving items which I have not requested.

For example, if I need items from 1st to 7th October, it includes items on the 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, etc.

the date format am using MMM d,yyyy

I have used the following code

```
String val1 = ((JTextField)jdate1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
String val2 = ((JTextField)jdate2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

String sql = " select * from Report_details where Date between '"+val1+"' and '"+val2+"' ";

// conn is some Connection                   
PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: are you sure that val1 and val2 are correctly formatted?

Comment: yes Lino, it seems it fetches all information where there is a one

Comment: You're using `PreparedStatement` wrong

Comment: The crux of your problem is that your dates are in a non ISO format which is just plain wrong for date literals in a SQL query.  Instead use this: `2017-10-16`

Comment: thanx tim, let me try it, if it fails i will come again.

Comment: Wait...I partially recant what I said.  The _best_ thing to do here would be to feed plain old Java `Date` objects to a prepared statement.  Let Java worry about the format.

Answer (score 1):

Do not trust user input.

```
String sql = "select * from Report_details where Date between ? and ?";    
....
Date dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy").parse(val1);
// better yet, have your date picker return a Date object
....
myStmt.setDate(1, dt1);
....
```

should be the way to go (or setTime or setTimestamp, depending on your table definition)

NB: do not copy paste this, just a hint to get you off in the right direction.

Comment: On the right track, but the OP still needs to get _dates_, not strings.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks @TimBiegeleisen, edited the answer to show that

Comment: I'll upvote, but I'd like to think that his UI widgets already have a `Date` behind them (or could themselves generate a date).  But this is on the OP not you IMO.